# How to convert matrix RGB to image in R

Tags: r, rgb, image-recognition

I am doing a course in coursera about machine learning in python and I want to reproduce the exercise in R.

So, basically the dataset are 64x64 cat images. You can download the full dataset 
 [here](https://github.com/andersy005/deep-learning-specialization-coursera/raw/master/01-Neural-Networks-and-Deep-Learning/week2/Programming-Assignments/datasets/train_catvnoncat.h5). And load it in R with the package "rhdf5" following the code:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("rhdf5")
library(rhdf5)
mydata_train_x <- h5read("./data_in/train_catvnoncat.h5","train_set_x")
```

What I obtain is an array as follows:

```
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19]
[1,]   17   22   25   25   27   28   30   31   32    34    35    36    35    34    33    33    32    31    30
[2,]   31   33   35   35   36   38   41   43   47    49    50    51    50    49    48    48    47    46    44
[3,]   56   59   62   62   64   67   69   73   76    79    82    82    81    79    79    79    78    76    75
     [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36]
[1,]    29    29    27    27    25    23    21    21    21    20    20    19    18    16    14    12    11
[2,]    44    44    44    42    41    40    41    42    41    40    39    39    38    38    37    37    36
[3,]    75    75    74    73    71    72    73    74    74    73    72    72    71    70    69    68    67
     [,37] [,38] [,39] [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45] [,46] [,47] [,48] [,49] [,50] [,51] [,52] [,53]
[1,]     9     7     7     4     3     2     2     1     1     1     0     1     1     2     0     1     1
[2,]    36    34    35    36    36    34    34    35    34    34    32    30    30    29    29    29    28
[3,]    66    64    66    69    69    65    65    67    67    66    63    61    62    59    59    59    58
     [,54] [,55] [,56] [,57] [,58] [,59] [,60] [,61] [,62] [,63] [,64]
[1,]     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
[2,]    28    28    28    28    25    25    27    28    28    26    22
[3,]    57    57    57    57    55    55    58    58    57    56    51

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19]
[1,]   25   28   30   30   31   33   34   35   35    35    36    38    37    36    36    35    34    33    32
[2,]   36   38   40   39   40   41   44   45   47    48    49    51    51    49    48    48    48    46    45
[3,]   62   64
...
```

So what I want to do is to convert these values to an image just to plot it. I have the plot of the image indexed with 25 which according to the exercise in python has to look as follows (idx 25):

[image]

Could you help me to obtain this result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `plot(as.raster(t(matrix_imagevector), max = 255))` would probably work. But that is just one row really assuming those three vectors are separate RGB values.

Comment: Yes I just realized that, I am going to edit the question, just give me a couple of minutes

Comment: @G5W I have modified the question, sorry

Comment: @MrFlick I have modified the question, please check it!

Comment: Please post a minimal, _self-contained_ example. It seems overkill to rely on external packages and download files 'only' to create an example array ;)

Comment: Sorry  @Henrik, but it is not easy to do it in this case.